# marker at 0 position does not show

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following code, why the 0 tick marks do not show?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center,axis line style={black, thick,-latex},
 tick style={line width=.04cm, color=black, line cap=round},
 font=\normalsize,color=black,
 xmin=0,xmax=64,
 xtick={0,16,32},xticklabels={0,16,32},
 ymin=0,ymax=16,
 ytick={0,4,8},yticklabels={0,4,8},
 tickwidth=.2cm,
 xlabel={P}, xlabel style={right},
 ylabel={M}, ylabel style={above},
 xticklabel style={inner xsep=0cm, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.1cm},
 yticklabel style={inner ysep=0cm,xshift=-.1cm,yshift=0cm},
 samples=200]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's due to the `axis lines=center` option. The axis themselves are the 'ticks' at 0. You can use `axis y line=left,axis x line=bottom` because `left` and `bottom` in your case are the same as `center` (at 0).

Comment: When I removed the (axis lines=center,) the axes labels appear at the bottom and left of the corresponding axes. So I kept this code, and added yours also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So according to your (mysteriously disappearing) comments you would like to:

- Show the `0` ticklabels
- Not show the `0` tick marks
- Place the axis labels at the end of their axes

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\begin{axis}[
    axis y line=left,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis line style={black, thick,-latex},
    tick style={line width=.04cm, color=black, line cap=round},
    font=\normalsize,
    color=black,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=64,
    xtick={16,32},
    extra x ticks = {0},
    extra y ticks= {0},
    extra tick style={tick style={draw=none}},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=16,
    ytick={4,8},
    tickwidth=.2cm,
    xlabel={P}, 
    every axis x label/.style={
        at = {(ticklabel* cs:1)},
        anchor = west
    },
    ylabel={M}, 
    every axis y label/.style={
        at = {(ticklabel* cs:1)},
        anchor = south
    },
    xticklabel style={inner xsep=0cm, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.1cm},
    yticklabel style={inner ysep=0cm,xshift=-.1cm,yshift=0cm},
    samples=200
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I am sorry for my (mysteriously disappearing) comments, when I make changes, something else come up, and I remove its comment. Your solution works fine.

Comment: @Hany Good to hear. May I ask why you use those options like `font=\normalsize` and `color=black`? I believe those are the default values.

Comment: I use these options because in different situations I need to modify them, so I include the codes for editing different situations.